# Oracle11g, Multiple Pivots

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I have a working query that pivots some data for me.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  select requisitions.ACC_ID AS "Accession #"
  ,tests.TEST_ID
  ,results.RESULT_NUMERIC
FROM requisitions

inner join req_panels ON requisitions.acc_id = req_panels.acc_id
inner join results ON req_panels.rp_id = results.rp_id
inner join tests ON results.test_id = tests.test_id

WHERE results.TEST_ID IN (1,2,3,4)
AND requisitions.RECEIVED_DATE > TO_DATE('9/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
ORDER BY requisitions.ACC_ID
)
pivot(
      MAX(RESULT_NUMERIC)
      for TEST_ID IN ('1' AS Test1,'2' AS Test2,'3' AS Test3,'4' AS Test4)
)
```

Now, I have to include a different type of result (RESULTS_ALPHA in results table) as a column for each ACC_ID. RESULT_ALPHA is a clob. For the test_id's already included in the code above RESULTS_ALPHA is empty. But it holds a value for another test, we'll call it "TestAlpha".

So what I have currently output from the code above is;

```
Acc_ID | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4
-------------------------------------------
000001 |   24   |   1.5  |   0.5  |  2.1
000002 |   15   |   2.1  |   0.3  |  1.3
```

And I need to get

```
Acc_ID | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4 | TestAlpha
--------------------------------------------------------
000001 |   24   |   1.5  |   0.5  |  2.1   |  abcd
000002 |   15   |   2.1  |   0.3  |  1.3   |  efgh
```

How can I accomplish this? Another pivot?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just add the extra column to the inner select list?

Comment: No. If I try to add results.results_alpha you get an error; ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: You're expecting the full CLOB in the output, or would a substring (<4k) do? Hard to see that much being useful?

Comment: The field I'm currently looking at including denotes an organism name, which should fit fine in <4k. They aren't that long. However other fields that they COULD potentially ask me to include in the output might not. If a have something I can try using a substring I'm willing to try. Ideally I'd like to find a better way. There are a bunch of tests that store results in results_alpha as CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use just the first 4000 characters of a CLOB field then you can just substring it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  select requisitions.ACC_ID AS "Accession #"
  ,tests.TEST_ID
  ,results.RESULT_NUMERIC
  ,dbms_lob.substr(results.RESULT_ALPHA, 4000, 1) as result_alpha
FROM requisitions
...
```

Of course that gives you a 4000-character-wide column in your output, but not much you can do about that really, unless you can set a lower length based on knowledge of what's in the column. (Though if it's less than 4K, it doesn't really make sense to store it as a CLOB; sounds like you have a mix of data in there though).

Even if the value is more than 4000 characters this will show the start of it. Whether that's acceptable, or useful, depends what you're doing with the result of the pivot.

What you're doing does seem to assume that the `RESULTS_ALPHA` is the same for all `results` records for each `TEST_ID`; or even for each `ACC_ID`. Which seems a bit wasteful if it's true.

I'm not sure if there a non-programmatic solution to get the full CLOB back.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the last paragraph a bit? I'm not sure I comprehend what you mean. Basically what I'm doing is using the Oracle DB for another piece of software that was built for the company I'm assisting. The software is for Clinical Laboratories (LIS software). I have a read only account to pull out particular information that the need to create reports in Excel for business partners. They can't grant full access to the software since it is HIPAA controlled. The results table contains unique results for 100's of tests. Some report numeric, others text, others #/text.

Comment: Also, this doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do. I think I might have to provide some sample data to help. What this did was create duplicates of the accession ID's (acc_id). It didn't append the "results_alpha" to the acc_id that is already listed with the various other tests (1,2,3,4). I believe this is because it isn't part of the pivot. And that is the issue, since I'm currently pivoting on result_numeric I don't think I can also pivot on results_alpha. Perhaps I have to have another pivot or use grouping?

Comment: I meant CLOBs are quite restrictive; they can't be in a group-by or order-by for example (so using the old manual pivot with lots of `case` statements doesn't work either). Although I'm assuming that you have multiple records - is that true, or are you only using `max()` because `pivot` forces you to use an aggregate? Also is `test_alpha` going to be the same for all `test_id` values for each `acc_id`? It's a bit hard to tell from your sample. More representative data (even with short CLOBs) might be useful.

Comment: @JayG30 - it does show the `report_alpha` field (though not at the end, you can fix that with an outer query) in my tests. But that also becomes part of the pivot group; so if an `acc_id` has more than one `report_alpha` you'll get more than one row back. Maybe whatever you're running this from isn't showing the extra field? Not sure.

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL. Taking a look at the data, there does seem to be multiple result_alpha for when test_id=resultalpha per accession (acc_id). I'll have to combine them into a single field. However, I still don't think it will work. The results I get basically show the same acc_id multiple times, once for any result_numeric results created by the pivot and another time(s) for the result_alpha. I'm trying to get sqlfiddle to work so I can give a better example but oracle 11g just isn't working for me at all. Not even simple stuff. MySQL seems to work fine.